# Geographical Project Web solution

Tags: geography, web

I support a NGO and they are looking for a way to put (let's say) 100 projects of theirs online.

They will consists of 
 - pictures
 - few lines of text
 - contact person for more detail and
 - (most important) a geographical component

The idea is that users of the webpage then can find projects in a city/country/region.

The software should offer nice presentation.

The NGO has its own Linux server currently running in a typical LAMP configuration. Installing any software is possible but there shouldn't be any recurring costs for the software.
The NGO employees should be able to easily enter data (GUI).

May be something like this: http://www.charitywater.org/projects/completed-projects/

Can anyone think of something like this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you a cartographer or a web developer ?

Comment: Neither: The best description would probably be "Sysadmin"

Comment: They only thing I can think of is ArcGIS online and it is what sound like you might want to look into. The link is https://www.arcgis.com/home/ and I would highly recommend you to go to ESRI's GeoNet ( https://geonet.esri.com/welcome ) and there might be others like you might have similar what you are doing.